# How to call write function of smart contract using C# Nethereum?

Tags: c#, smartcontracts, nethereum

Everyone.
I deployed this smart contract on Avalanche Testnet.

```
contract Storage {

uint256 number;

/**
 * @dev Store value in variable
 * @param num value to store
 */
function store(uint256 num) public {
    number = num;
}

/**
 * @dev Return value 
 * @return value of 'number'
 */
function retrieve() public view returns (uint256){
    return number;
}
```

}

I'm trying to call write function("store" in this contract) using Nethereum.

```
        Task<BigInteger> retrieveFunction = tmpContract.GetFunction("retrieve").CallAsync<BigInteger>();
        retrieveFunction.Wait();
        int result1 = (int)retrieveFunction.Result;


        //Prompts for the account address.
        Console.Write("Current stored amount: {0}\n", result1);
        string accountAddress = "0xa40e61095202Afe72dFfc4Aae70bc631429293B2";
                    
        BigInteger value = 450000;
        try
        {
            
            Task<string> storeFunction = tmpContract.GetFunction("store").SendTransactionAsync(accountAddress, value);
            storeFunction.Wait();
            Console.WriteLine("Succesfully Stored!");
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Error: {0}", e.Message);
        }
```

As a result, retrieve function is working well but in store function side, occurs errors.

Comment: you should call yourself 'expert', as you're doing something so unsual and new.

Comment: Please edit your question to show all the code and the results as *text* instead of as images. Also note that if you log the complete exception rather than just the message, you may well see more information, e.g. inner exceptions.

Answer (score 0):

The `SendTransactionAsync` method should receive a `TransactionInput` object; you need to create the `TransactionInput` before sending the transaction, and define the amount of gas to pay for writing in the blockchain.

```
//Number to store
var n = new Nethereum.Hex.HexTypes.HexBigInteger(450000);

//  Create the transaction input
var transactionInput = yourFunction.CreateTransactionInput(account.Address, new Nethereum.Hex.HexTypes.HexBigInteger(5000000), null, null, n);

// Send the transaction
var transactionHash = await web3.Eth.TransactionManager.SendTransactionAsync(transactionInput);
```

`yourFunction` should be the instance of `GetFunction("store")`.

The gas in the example above is 5000000.